# Most elegant way to search for a json value and replace it in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table called `Entity` which stores a bunch of jsons.

```
Entity
ID | Json
```

The Json is basically a array of json objects.
The order of the json objects is different each time...

```
[
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity",
        "id" : 0,
        "tag" : "player",
        "typeID" : "3:1"
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.transform.Transform",
        "position" : {
            "x" : 51.845858,
            "y" : 8.299743
        },
        "previousPos" : null
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.collision.RangeCollider",
        "range" : 0.000100
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.transform.Movement",
        "moveTo" : null,
        "speed" : 0.001000
    },
    {
        "baseDamage" : 2,
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.combat.PhysicalDamage",
        "damage" : 0
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.graphical.Mesh",
        "id" : 6
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.items.Inventory"
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.combat.Health",
        "health" : 100,
        "maxHealth" : 100
    },
    {
        "attackSpeed" : 1,
        "baseAttackSpeed" : 1,
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.combat.AttackSpeed"
    },
    {
        "class" : "com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.animation.AnimationController",
        "controllerName" : "standardAnimationController"
    }
]
```

I want to replace some of the class paths, add new fields to the json object, modify existing ones or remove them.

For example, i want to replace `com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity` with `com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity`, add a new "name" field to the same json object, adjust the existing tag and remove the typeID completly.

What is the most elegant/easiest way of modifiying that Json array in MySQL ?

Comment: SQL JSON functions are really clumsy. This may be possible, but it will be complex. My recommendation is to normalize your schema instead of using JSON.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks ! A migration would take much longer than solving this issue here :/ My biggest problem is actually the lack of good examples and documentation... i saw dozends of different functions and weird syntax like this `json->"$[*].class"`... the tutorials are clearly outdated

Comment: That's the right syntax for access JSON elements in MySQL, it's not outdated.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html for the current documentation

Comment: @Barmar Thanks ! Do you know how these are called ? Way better than those other functions... and can you also update values with the same syntax ?

Comment: Google "mysql json cookbook" to find sites with example code for common operations.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot ! That was actually helpfull :D I suddenly find many good sites, mostly from medium but the examples are great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the element of the json array given a value:

```
mysql> select substring_index(json_unquote(json_search(json, 'one', 'com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity')), '.', 1) as element from entity;
+---------+
| element |
+---------+
| $[0]    |
+---------+
```

That gives the location of the element you need to replace. Then you can use JSON_REPLACE() to change it, something like this:

```
UPDATE Entity SET json = 
  json_replace(json, 
    substring_index(json_unquote(json_search(json, 'one', 'com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity')), '.', 1),
    json_object(
      'class', 'com.parallelorigin.code.ecs.components.Identity', 
      'id', 0, 
      'name', 'some name')
  )
WHERE id = 1;
```

That *is* the method, but there's nothing elegant about it. That's typical of using JSON in MySQL. Using JSON in an SQL database usually makes data manipulation much harder.

Using JSON in MySQL, you are practically certain to experience the [Inner-Platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

The elegant solution would be to store the data in a normalized fashion.